# Why can't I craft a sawmill?

Tags: terraria

According to [Terraria wiki](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Sawmill) entry for Sawmill crafting; it requires the following:

- 10 Wood
- 2 Iron Bars
- 1 Iron Chain

As shown in the screenshot below, I'm meeting all the requirements(rather I've more objects than required)

[image: Terraria]

As can be seen; I have 32 wood, 15 Iron bars and 1 Iron chain(3rd row, 5th column). Still no option to craft a sawmill is displayed either on workbench or on Anvil!

Is this a bug?

#### EDIT

I should mention that it is a multi-player instance(in case, it has anything to do with the issue).

Comment: Silly question - have you tried scrolling the crafting list?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I guess I did. How'd I get a gold sword otherwise?

Comment: Have you tried moving your workbench away from your table/chair? Try without any other potential crafting options available?

Comment: something similar happened to me like this several months ago. I forgot how I solved it. I'll give an answer once I find out. This person seems to have your problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfBJPRDJNeY

Comment: There are some multiplayer bugs along this line, have you tried it in a single player world? Should be easy enough to move the workbench over to a new world?

Comment: If you ask the guide about crafting, stick the wood in and scroll to the workbench, then move the mouse away, does it say you require just a workbench, or a workbench and anvil? If both, then you need to be near enough to both of the stations at once.

Comment: @McKay Tried it in single player. It is not available there either.

Comment: @Samthere Tried with single workbech, a pair of them, a workbench and an anvil, a workbench, anvil and a fireplace placed close. None of them display Sawmill in available crafting items.

Comment: Oh, I just got it - answering.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I notice you don't have cosmetic equipment slots, so I think you must be on an older version of the game.

Sawmills were added in 1.0.6.1, and social item slots were added in 1.0.4.

Comment: Well deduced Samthere!

Comment: Yet, I have 1.3.0.7 and still can't craft it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  The only way I could make the sawmill was to put the workbench right by the Guide person, talk to him about Crafting, click on one of the sawmill ingridients, and BOOM, it let me make it.  Had to do the same with the anvil to make a grappling hook too.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Talking to the guide seemed to worked in my case too. Maybe it's a glitch.

Comment: You are my hero! I was beginning to stop enjoying the game, because I did not get any new recipes. Now it's full of new things to try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I switched the metal in my inventory from tin to lead and it suddenly worked.